# How to find an infected column in SSIS

Tags: excel, ssis

I have a huge Table with so many fields. I am trying to dump its data into Excel from OLE DB Source to Excel Destination. When run, it issues this Error: 
[Excel Destination [2]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x00040EDA. An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft JET Database Engine"  Hresult: 0x80040E21  Description: "Numeric field overflow.".

Apparently there would be some problem with datatype in the source data. but it doesn't say which field is cause of the error. As I have tens of fields in the table finding the infected column would be a real pain this way. Is there any way that I can get to the field name directly through SSIS?

Any help would be considerably appreciated

Comment: I am very new with SSIS, but maybe this link will help you: http://sqlage.blogspot.com/2013/07/ssis-how-to-redirect-invalid-rows-from.html. You can redirect wrong rows to some output and so you will see what is wrong...

Comment: Thanks @Darka, I have already done that. But as the number of Error rows and number of columns are so many, I have around 70 columns!, finding erroneous columns are still difficult.

Comment: Actually the error column in the output is -1 so it is unidentifiable.

Comment: Referring to a problematic column as "infected" is most excellent.

Comment: The error message says it all. Do you have many numeric columns? If not, you should be able to narrow it down to a smaller subset. On the destination, you will need to ignore those mappings one after the other to find out the column on which the package fails or does not fail. This will be helpful. But there's no short cut to this.

Comment: @rvphx, Believe it or not the Access table ,which comes from medieval era :), has 219 columns, I have sort of found the error,divide and conquer!, the problem has nothing to do with the numeric types to my best knowledge. There is (a) date column(s) in the table with some invalid date values,like 21/03/143 see medieval time!, As we need the data for now I had to modify the excel sheet DML query and that works now. But the thing that SSIS can not point you the right erroneous column and instead show a misleading message is really unacceptable. Thanks anyway.